# How can I cancel a state change from a resolving promise after component is already unmounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**The Context:**

I want to know how to get rid of this error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

I think I know exactly why this error shows up:

I have a Signin Route. I have a litte piece of code in the `useEffect` that does this:

`if (!auth.isEmpty && auth.isLoaded) {
      history.push("/");
    }`

So when someone goes to mypage/signin and is already signed in, he gets redirected to Homepage. This works fine BUT:

**The Problem:**

When he is not signed in I have a little Signin Function:

```
const signin = async (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const user = await firebase.login({ email, password });
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (user) {
        history.push("/");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };
```

So when the users hits enter, he gets redirected to home when there is no error. It works fine but I get this error in the console, because I set the state and the the snippet in useEffect routes me to /Home, but the promise is not yet completed from firebase. And when it's finished it tries to set state, but component already unmounted.

**What have I tried**

I added a `isMounted` hook and changed my signin function to look like this:

```
const signin = async (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (isMounted) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const user = await firebase.login({ email, password });
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (user) {
          history.push("/");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(error.message);
      }
    }
  };
```

But still the same error on route change.

**Additional Info**

Don't get confused about these 2 loading states `auth.isLoaded` (from `react-redux-firebase`) and `isLoading` (my own state). Basically why I did it this way is, because when someone is already logged in and then goes to /signin he sees the login form for a tiny moment, because firebase doesn't know yet if user is authenticated, so I handled it like this, so the user definetily sees a spinner and then gets redirected if already logged in.

How to solve this little problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React hooks for this. The useEffect return method is called when compoment is unmonuted from screen. This is like compomentdidunmount in class based react.

declare global variable _isMounted to false. When useEffect is called, it changes to true and components are on screen. 
If component are unmounted, then return method from useEffect is called and _isMounted is set to false;

while updating the state, you can check using _isMounted variable that is component is mounted or not.

```
var _isMounted = false;

const fetchuser = () => {
   if(_isMounted)
   {
       // code
   }
}

useEffect(() => {

    _isMounted = true;
    // your code;

   return()
   {
      _isMounted = false;
      console.log("Component Unmounted");
   }

},[])
```

Comment: I will try this thank you! It's the same idea like this right: https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted

Comment: No sorry. I edited my post, now I only run code if it's mounted, but I still get the same error / warning.

Comment: Can you please also add UseEffect hook in answer.

Comment: It works now. I slightly changed my function to look like this: https://pastebin.com/jQfFBqNM

Thank you for your help. I will acceppt your answer!

Answer (score 0):

if you redirected after login, you dont have to change loading state. Just remove setIsLoading(false)

```
const user = await firebase.login({ email, password });
if (user) {
   history.push("/");
}
```

Comment: I need it, because I just redirect if it has loaded and i have user object.